# React Native with Redux : state changes not showing in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

When I put `console.log('test')` statements in my reducer, I can see them in the console when the actions are called. But I'm not seeing the redux "NEXT STATE"/ "PREV STATE" stuff in the console.

Is there anything basic I could be missing?

**In the code below - I'm not trying to make any real functionality happen, I'm just trying to setup redux and see the state change in the console (so I know I'm on the correct path).**

---

**Container**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react-native';
import Header from './Header';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { leave } from './actions';
import { join } from './actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    in: state.in
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    join: (id) => {
      dispatch(join(id))
    },
    leave: (id) => {
      dispatch(leave(id))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

**Reducer**

```
export default function Header(state = { in: false }, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LEAVE':
      return {
        ...state,
        in: false
      }
    case 'JOIN':
      console.log(state);
      console.log(action);
      console.log('join');
      return {
        ...state,
        in: true
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Actions**

```
export const join = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'JOIN',
    payload: {
      in: true
    }
  }
}

export const leave = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'LEAVE',
    payload: {
      in: false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May be you should provide some code, for ex. reducers or action creators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It solved when I realized that https://github.com/fcomb/redux-logger is needed to be installed separately.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already identified, you need to install redux-logger middleware.
https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger

From their docs:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';

// Logger with default options
import logger from 'redux-logger'
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(logger)
)
```

I only do this when in a dev environment

```
const middlewares = [];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') {
  middlewares.push(logger);
}
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
)
```

Comment: where to place the second code of middlewares ... i mean what is meant by dev environment ?